# C#: Chrome - User downloading an excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, webforms

I have the following code to prompt the user's browser to download an excel file. This is C# code in a ASP.NET web forms

```
byte[] fileData = GetExcelFile(..);
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=report.xlsx");
Response.OutputStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
Response.OutputStream.Flush();
Response.OutputStream.Close();
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
Response.End();
```

This code is triggered when the user clicks on a button on a website.

It works perfectly in IE11; user gets a dialog asking if they want to save or open the file. The file is opened fine.

However, on Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (latest version), the user gets the a 'Failed - Network' and "Failed to load response data" error, and nothing gets downloaded on their computer. This section of the code hasn't been changed in over a year, and has been working for a year. However, I tested it yesterday, and it stopped working.

Is this the recommended way of sending the Excel file to the user as a response

Comment: Web Forms, MVC, API, Core?

Comment: You are using the wrong content type for `xlsx` documents.

Comment: Open the browser console a d look at the console and network tabs, it will tell you why it has failed.

Comment: Are you really creating an `xlsx` file or something else? You don't need to do all that flushing and closing. Simply writing the data to the response stream should be enough

Comment: Try adding in the content-length header.

Comment: For example, check [EPPlus's Web Application sample](https://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample). All you need is `Response.BinaryWrite`. The *content-type* though has to be `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: BTW closing the output stream prematurely *is* a network failure from the browser's perspective. Have you tried a simple `Response.BinaryWrite(fileData);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of flushing and closing the output data, just write the data with [Response.BinaryWrite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.binarywrite(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also ensure you use the *correct* content type. `xlsx` files are compressed XML. The correct content type for `xlsx` files is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`.

For example, assuming EPPlus is used to create the Excel file :

```
    private void DumpExcel(DataTable tbl)
    {
        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            //Create the worksheet
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");

            //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(tbl, true);

            byte[] fileData =pck.GetAsByteArray();

           //Write it back to the client
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx");
            Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
        }
    }
```

You may have to call `Response.End();` to prevent the server from sending the rest of your page on the same response.

Another option is to use `ExcelPackage.SaveAs(Stream)` to write the file directly to the output stream. This eliminates the temporary buffer:

```
    pck.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How did you verify that application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet is the correct content type?

Comment: Also, I tried your solution and it works. However, when the file opens in Excel, I receive a "Excel found unreadable content in '... xlsx'. "Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook?" Could this be related to the solution.

Comment: It's a well-known content type. The one you used is for the old `xls` files.

Comment: @user2769810 did you create a *real* xlsx file? Or did you send a CSV file or  HTML table ? That's why I mentioned EPPlus. It's a common hack to send HTML or CSV files with faked extensions instead of actual `xlsx` files. The error you mentioned is a common one in these cases, as Excel tries to import that text file. EPPlus on the other hand creates real Open XML spreadsheets (ie `xlsx`). The file is a lot smaller too. `xlsx` uses gzip compression

Comment: Yes, it is a real xlsx file.

Comment: I closed it with Response.End and the ""Excel found unreadable content" goes away. Thanks the great help

Answer (score 0):

You could try this,

```
Response.Buffer = true;

Response.Clear();

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=yourExcelFileName.xlsx;");

Response.BinaryWrite(yourByteArray);

Response.End();
```